# Scipy loadmat results in 'file not found message'

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, ipython

I have been working on translating code to Matlab. The code uses some data that is stored in a .mat file. I have been writing this:

```
mat_file = sio.loadmat('USGS_1995_Library.mat')
datalib = mat_file['datalib']
names = mat_file['names']
```

to try to open and store the files. However every time I run the code, there is an error message saying "No such file or directory: 'USGS_1995_Libary.mat". I have made sure that the file is in the same folder as the code is. If it makes any difference I have been trying to run the code in iPython.

I am not sure if I am incorrectly using loadmat or if it is the file itself that is not working the way it is supposed to or if loadmat itself cannot do what I am asking it to do.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a way that I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your working directory at runtime is probably not the one you think it is. The location of a script is not what is used when resolving paths, but where you run it from. Try printing the result of `os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` in your script to confirm what your runtime working directory is. Other than that, using an absolute path for your file rather than a relative file is typically a good idea in general.

Comment: In `ipython` you can do `$ls` or `$ls USGS_1995_Library.mat` to check whether the file is present the current working directory.  `%pwd` also displays the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to delete the '.mat' in both the code and the file that you want to call. It works for me.